# Переименовать ключи и соединить масивы JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть переменная которая хранит в себе несколько массивов с подмассивами:
Как создать новый масив со всеми значениями и и дать имена ключам чтобы получилось:

Суть кода с которым работаю - сохранить веденные данные.
Данные передавались **методом POST из формы**, с большим количеством данных через инпуты не удобно работать, переделал все на обработку библиотекой handsontable.
**Теперь все данные передаются ajax"ом в выде массива, который надо подстроить под тот что уходил из фомы.**
Работа с данными и их отправка для наглядности [http://jsfiddle.net/zetwin/ccb4fd9y/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/zetwin/ccb4fd9y/3/#). 
Смотря в Firebug Массив который передается имеет вид:

```
 people[0][]Bob
 people[0][]Eshton
 people[0][]Ingeneer
 people[0][]28 years
 people[1][]John
 people[1][]Smit
 people[1][]Driver
 people[1][]20 years
```

А тот который передается из формы

```
people[name][]Bob
people[second][]Eshton
people[work][]Ingeneer
people[age][]28 years
people[name][]John
people[second][]Smit
people[work][]Driver
people[age][]20 years
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Пока получилось изменить наименование массивов в пхп вот таким методом:

```
foreach ($_POST['peoples'] as $peoples){

        $peoples['name'] = $peoples[0];
        $peoples['work'] = $peoples[1];
        $peoples['age'] = $peoples[2];

        unset( $peoples[0] );
        unset( $peoples[1] );
        unset( $peoples[2] );

      print_r($peoples);
     };
```

Ответ сервера при этом:

```
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [work] => driver
    [age] => 20
)
Array
(
    [name] => Bob
    [work] => doctor
    [age] => 28

)
```

Как объединить все в один массив, результат которого должен быть:

```
Array
(
    [name] => John
    [work] => driver
    [age] => 20
    [name] => Bob
    [work] => doctor
    [age] => 28
)
```

Comment: Обходите внешний массив в цикле, обрабатывайте подмассивы и сохраняйте значения. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: А еще лучше, покажите ваш код, с указанием на то, что конкретно не работает.

Comment: **e**ng**i**neer, Smit**h**, соед**и**нить

Comment: Изменил вопрос, добавил пример

Comment: @zetwin, я имел ввиду код, которым _вы пытаетесь проводить преобразование_ вложенных массивов в объект. А конкретика по клиентской части делает вопрос только менее понятным. Она здесь не нужна.

Comment: Изменил вопрос, уточнил

Comment: В последнем блоке кода, у вас одному и тому же ключу соответствуют разные значения. Это не имеет смысла и не реализуемо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так и не понял что именно вы хотите сделать, но попробую ткнуть пальцем в небо:

```
var people = [ 
    ['john', 'doctor', '19 years'],
    ['bob', 'manager', '23 years'],
    ['rob', 'driver', '25 years'],
    ['nick', 'dairy', '21 yers'],
    ['jane', 'engineer', '16 years']
];

var results = {
    name: [],
    work: [],
    age: []
};

// Вместо for можно использовать Array.prototype.forEach, $.each
// или любой другой итератор. Мне вот нравится "for".
for (var i = 0, l = people.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Обходим внешний массив и преобразовываем результаты.
    results.name.push(people[i][0]);
    results.work.push(people[i][1]);
    results.age.push(people[i][2]);
}

console.dir(results);
```

А вот и JSFiddle с кодом: http://jsfiddle.net/gwjok4r1/

Comment: Я понял, проблема в том что массив формируется пообьектно, тоесть в нашем случае по человеку, а как сформировать по свойствам? Чтобы получился масив People со свойствами name[], work[], age[], в которых уже данные к которым будем обращаться по индексу типа name[3].

Comment: @zetwin, обновил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Вы мне очень помогли это был финал моих мучений!!! Но с вашей помошью я сделал это! большое спасибо!!!!